# How do I encrypt a password in the configuration file used in jooq?

Tags: jooq

Just following this sample here: https://blog.jooq.org/2016/01/14/reactive-database-access-part-3-using-jooq-with-scala-futures-and-actors/.

I noticed the password tags in the mentions.xml file. In a production environment is the password stored in clear text or is it encrypted? How can it be encrypted?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most people do not generate code from a production environment but from a development environment, in case of which the password is usually not really sensitive information that shouldn't be stored in the configuration file.

If you must absolutely protect your password in your jOOQ code generation configuration file, you could:

- [Use programmatic configuration](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-programmatic/), in case of which you can do whatever you want, including decrypting things.
- Use Maven and load the password from an encrypted properties file, using an appropriate plugin (or writing your own plugin, perhaps).

Comment: ok, thanks, sorry, I didn't express myself properly - you are right, I would not use the production environment to generate the code. Somehow I thought that this is where you specify the password for normal connections to the database. I got it mixed up.